GetExternalLoginInfoAsync returns the wrong user
We're using AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp to authenticate our users against EntraID. In the EntraID I have two users with two different email and udp. I can log in with either user, but after logging out, it will always default to the last user, and I will not be asked to provide username/password again.
Setup in ConfigureServices:
foreach (var section in Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetChildren())
{
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(section, section.Key, null)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
}

This is where info
Logout
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    return LocalRedirect("/");
}

Question: Is there anything I can do to make sure the user needs to provide credentials after logout?
PS1. If I log in using a private incognito window it works, but not if I clear all cookies and sessions.
PS2. I also got a feeling that if I've logged in with one of the EntraID accounts on an other site, this will reset the default account for our site
